# Change the Open With associations

Tags: windows-10, maya

I have several different versions of a 3D program installed(Maya), but Windows does not let me choose which one I want to use to open .mb and .ma files. It always open with the oldest version I have, which I do not want.
I have installed Maya 2017, 2018 and 2019.

Right-click > Open With > Choose another App > Look for another App on this PC - and then choosing the .exe in the bin directory of Maya 2019 still opens the file with Maya 2017.
Why is that?

Using this in the command prompt as an admin:
REG ADD "HKCR.mb\shell\Maya2019\command" /VE /D "\"C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2019\bin\maya.exe\" \"%1\""

My new context menu, if I press on 'Choose another app', looks like this:
[contextMenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCO9n.png).

The first 'Maya' entry is the Maya 2017 version and I do not know where the 'C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2018\bin\maya.exe" "%1" comes from.

The thing is that my context menu, when I simply press right click on the file, looks like this:
[contextMenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QfpE.png).
It does not have any Maya option.

Comment: [Fix: Cannot Add a Program to Open with List in Windows](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/cant-add-program-to-open-with-menu-list-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of messing with the Windows Open With context menu, I would suggest to add own context menu for .ma and .mb extensions only. Run the following command in Command Prompt as administrator:

```
REG ADD "HKCR\.ma\shell\Maya2019\command" /VE /D "\"C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2019\bin\maya.exe\" \"%1\""
```

Right click on `.ma` file, there will be Maya2019 entry, click on it. Use double quote if that path contains space. Repeat the same command for other versions and other extensions as well. The context menu appears only for the specified extensions.

Note: The `%1` is the placeholder of the opened file and the backslash is to instruct Command Prompt to tread the double quote as a character.